# Variable assignment impossible, debugger - variable <not available> Help from the best needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the situation:

```
function vartest(a, b, c){
  var angle =b;
  var speed = a;
  var  g=c;
  var time=0.5, v0, angle1;
  v0 = speed;
  alert("Type of angle 1"+typeof(angle1));
  window.alert("angle "+angle);
  angle1 = (angle*3.14)/180; 
  alert("Type of angle 1 second try: "+typeof(angle1));
  window.alert("angle1 "+ angle1 ); 
 }
 //sliders from which i take angle, speed and gravity acceleration
 $(function(){
  $(".slider").slider()
  $("#angle").slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:250,
    step:0.2,
    slide: function (event, ui){
       $( "#angres" ).html( ui.value );
       angle = ui.value;
      // trajgen();
      }
    });
  $("#speed").slider({
    value:0,
    min:0,
    max:250,
    step:0.2,
    slide: function (event, ui){
      $("#spdres").html(ui.value);
      speed = ui.value;
     // trajgen();
     }
   });
  $("#gravity").slider({
    value:9.8,
    min:0,
    max:250,
    step:0.2,
    slide: function(event, ui){
      $("#gravres").html(ui.value);
      g = ui.value;
     // trajgen();
     }
   });   
  });

 //a fair attempt to assign the variable below with the initial values of 
 // the sliders, debugger shows that this doesn't work, it's OK but does not
 // assign anything
 $("#angres").html($('#angle').slider('value'));
 var angle = $( "#angle" ).slider( "option", "value" );
 $("#spdres").html( $("#speed").slider('value'));
 var speed = $( "#speed" ).slider( "option", "value" );
 $("#gravres").html($("#gravity").slider('value'));
 var g = $( "#gravity" ).slider( "option", "value" );

if(speed!=undefined&&angle!=undefined&&g!=undefined){
  vartest(angle, speed, g);
}
```

And the problem is - after sliders are adjusted they successfully pass `angle`, `speed` and `gravity` to `vartest` but later, when it comes to `angle1 = (angle*3.14)/180` it lets `angle1` = 'not available'. How to fix this. I'm fighting this problem 4th day and due to a lot of effort and help of one guy here I was able to change `angle1` from `NaN` to 'not available'. I should admit that even now while initializing `angle1` is a `NaN` but unlike the previous attempt now this `angle1` changes from `NaN` to 'not available', which is a fair progress. However, `angle1`'s type is number regardless before or after the `angle1= (angle*3.14)/180;` line. If there are no slider functions and I set angle with a value let's say `angle =150` then `angle1` works.

Comment: Why not `var time=0.5, v0=speed, angle1;` at the beginning?

Comment: excuse me, I'm changing the code for Nth time today and it wasn't the proper one, now it's better

Comment: but however it's still not working.... See here:
[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/fksg75.png[/IMG]

Comment: as you can see v0=speed part is also not working which means wherever I 'm assigning one variable over another, or a calculated expression it returns not available which is equal to not doing anything.

Comment: When does this code run?  Is the document ready and do the elements exist at the point that you select them and initialize them?  In your `vartest` function, what is the type and value of `angle`?  That will determine the resulting type of the multiplication and division operations that create the value for `angle1`.

Comment: Ok, I have 3 sliders and one div. With the sliders I control angle, speed and gravity variables, the div is the place where onclick I place a ball(an img file) which the script'll take as (0;0), on the next step I want to draw the path of this ball with smaller red dots by calculating x and y and increasing their time. I made vartest() because I found that my main problem is the initialization of the variables, particularly The type of angle is number alongside with speed and gravity, as I take them on slide, you drag the slider, depending on left or right direction those vars will increase

Comment: or decrease. The strange thing here is that vartest() receives it's three parameters successfully and when it comes to angle1 = (angle*3.14)/180 angle1 is not available, but meanwhile chome's element inspector says that exactly in this line 'angle' has been with assigned value, which means that angle has a value already.See at the bottom of the script I've given, I invoke vartest() when all the sliders were being adjusted to some position, different from the initial

Comment: I can't find why but when you load the whole project and still leave sliders untouched, in their initial static position, appears that angle, speed and gravity vars don't get 'option:value', from each of their associated slider  which causes angle, speed and gravity to remain 'undefined' until you move the three sliders to somewhere and actually the piece of code unter the three line comments you see doesn't work.